# Thunderbird: How to increase the number subfolders in recent folder?

Tags: directory, thunderbird

Is now: TB Version 102.13.0

Problem:

[image: TB folders]

I can copy to / move to only 7 (sub)folders.
I want to have more (sub)folders as e.g. 10.
How can I change the TB configuration to meet my requirement?

Thx in advance for your hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved because it is not a problem.

[image: TB folders]

If I copy /move a message to a "next" folder, this folder will be included into the hinged folder.

The maximum of entries in the folder may be configured like [Sebastian](https://www.wild-inter.net/posts/number-recent-folders-thunderbird) .